# I want to check if std_logic_vector contains negative integer

Tags: vhdl

How can I check with if (...) then ... end if; construction if std_logic_vector variable holds the bits of a negative number? If it is negative, I have to assign it a zero value.
I have :

```
signal sum : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
sum<= (...);
if (...) then
   sum<=x"00";
end if;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot add two `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`s, because the language does not know anything about the arithmetic that it should perform. This is because, to the synthesis tool, every signal/port/variable that's declared as `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` is nothing more than an array of `STD_LOGIC`, the multi-valued logic type. Arithmetic on such a type does not make sense.

If you want to use arithmetic on types whose interface is similar to the one exposed by `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`, you should use `SIGNED` (for signed arithmetic) and `UNSIGNED` (for unsigned arithmetic) types defined in `IEEE.NUMERIC_STD`. In order to convert between these types, just cast them using the type names explicitly, like this :

```
std_logic_vector_variable := STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned_variable);
unsigned_variable := UNSIGNED(std_logic_vector_variable);
```

So, summing it all up - the `signal sum` should be declared as `SIGNED`, since you're obviously going to perform arithmetic on it. Then, you can freely use the comparison and arithmetic operations that you need. The resulting code should look more or less like this :

```
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
-- entity and architecture declarations...
signal sum : SIGNED (15 downto 0);
-- inside some process...
if (sum <= 0) then sum <= 0; end if;
```

Answer (score 2):

The quick and simple hack is to check if the most-significant-bit is 1, indicating a negative number:

```
result <= (others=>'0') when sum(sum'left)='1' else sum;
```

Or you can coerce the std_logic_vector into an appropriate type and see if it is negative:

```
result <= (others=>'0') when signed(sum) < 0 else sum;
```

Or inside of a process use an if statement instead of a selected signal assignment:

```
if signed(sum) < 0 then
    result <= (others=>'0');
else
    result <= sum;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
signal sum : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);

sum<= x"E8";

if (sum(15)='1') then

   sum<=x"00";

end if;
```

Just check the MSB..

If MSB is 1, that means the number is negative else positive.